# Is there a built-in function for PHP for me to check whether two arrays contain the same values ( order is important?)

Tags: php

For example, I want a function that returns me true for the following two inputs:

```
array('4','5','2') 
array('4','5','2')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options depending on what you want:

just use a straight `if`

```
 if($array === $array2)
```

or you can use [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) which will give you an output array of any differences.

```
 $diff = array_diff($array, $array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can check that both arrays are the same or not using the array_diff function.

```
$a1=array("4","5","2");
$a2=array("4","5","2");

$result=array_diff($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

If Both arrays are not the same than it will return difference else return a blank array.

Comment: Where is the condition - order is important?

Answer (score 0):

If the 2 arrays are "identical", meaning that types are the same, than you can use the triple = comparison. If types are not identical, you could use the double = comparison.

```
$array1 = array('4', '5', '2');
$array2 = array('4', '5', '2');

var_dump($array1 == $array2); // true;
var_dump($array1 === $array2); // true;
```

VS

```
$array1 = array('4', '5', '2');
$array2 = array(4, 5, 2);

var_dump($array1 == $array2); // true;
var_dump($array1 === $array2); // false;
```